# How do I make a Makefile to log both command and its output to a file?

Tags: logging, makefile, gnu-make

I want to log both the command and its output to a log file. It seems easy. Just redirect stdout to the log file.

```
myrule:  
  mycommand >> logfile
```

But this only logs the output of the command. Not the command itself.
Do I also echo the command and redirect that output to the log file?

```
myrule:
  @echo mycommand >> logile
  mycommand >> logfile
```

This duplication of 'mycommand' doesn't look good and it takes up space in the recipe. Especially if the recipe is long.

Should I create a function and call it for every command I want to log?

```
define log_and_run
@echo $(1) >> logfile
$(1) >> logfile
endef

myrule:
  $(call log_and_run,mycommand)
```

Now I don't have to duplicate 'mycommand'. But now 'mycommand' is less visible in the recipe. Attention is on the 'call', not on 'mycommand'.

And what if 'mycommand' is something like

```
$(CC) -o $@ -Wl,--linkeroption $<
```

The comma will split the command into two arguments when calling 'log_and_run'.

Does anybody have a solution for this that doesn't take attention away from the commands and works for arbitrary commands?

Comment: Given all the requirements you have, there is no better way to do it than the ones you've already come up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the shell do all the heavy lifting, maybe? I.e. something like this:

```makefile
.PHONY: all myrule myrule-with-macro
all: myrule myrule-with-macro

mycommand = echo "Running $@..."

myrule:
    (set -x; $(mycommand)) >>$@.log 2>&1

define log_and_run
(set -x; $(1)) >>$@.log 2>&1
endef

myrule-with-macro:
    $(call log_and_run,$(mycommand))
```

Test run:

```
$ make
(set -x; echo "Running myrule...") >>myrule.log 2>&1
(set -x; echo "Running myrule-with-macro...") >>myrule-with-macro.log 2>&1

$ ls myrule*.log
myrule.log  myrule-with-macro.log

$ cat myrule*.log
+ echo 'Running myrule...'
Running myrule...
+ echo 'Running myrule-with-macro...'
Running myrule-with-macro...
```

Comment: Nice!. I forgot about 'set -x'. And as each command in a recipe runs in in its own shell instance, there should be no need for a macro or anything.  Just `myrule: ; set -x; mycommand &>> $@.log`

Comment: Please remember [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: And with two macros for the start and the end of the logging it looks real good.  
`LS := (set -x;  \n
LE = ) &>> $(LOGFILE)  \n
myrule:  \n
    $(LS) mycommand $(LE)  
`

Comment: in this example we have commands set to stored into `mycommand` variable, however there should  be a way to store everything being run on sent to stdout sent to log

Answer (score 1):

It is a default behaviour of make to print both the command and its output to stdout.
An obvious solution is to just have

```
myrule:  
    mycommand
```

but then call `make myrule > logfile`.

If you want to do the redirection from within the Makefile, you can [invoke make recursively](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html) from a special target based on some variable being set (or not set).

Comment: That may work for the simple case. But what if I have several targets (and I have) in my Makefile and want each target to log to its own logfile?

Comment: And the logfile's name should be based on the target name.

Comment: @rAAbert: 1) You ought to have mentioned that in the question, and 2) recursive Make can handle it.

Comment: I'd rather not use recursion. In my real use case  have just rewritten a recursive makefile to a non-recursive. This cut the build time in half. Is it possible to do it non-recursively?

Comment: For this case you just need 1 level of recursion, don't see how it makes your build much slower. If you want it to work for all targets, my suggestion is to invoke make like so : `make LOG=YES myrule`, then in the makefile if LOG=YES define a "catch all" target [like so](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Last-Resort.html#Last-Resort). In this target you can run make with LOG=NO and output redirection. Then there's no more recursion, it works as a plain make. Note: If LOG=NO the last resort target must be undefined. An advantage is that your target recipes are clean from cruft.

Comment: @Beta Could you please ellaborate.

Comment: @batll Wouldn't this log to only one logfile?

Comment: Yes, that's a single log file. I see what you want now. Stefan's approach works. An alternative solution would be to add unique markers for each target in this log file (could be as simple as `echo "start target $@"`, `echo "end target $@"`), and then pipe this combined log file to a separate script that splits it into multiple files. awk is good for this kind of task.

Comment: @rAAbert: elaborate on what? You said you didn't want to use recursion.