# How to auto create a build log file for c++ project

Tags: c++, c, makefile, logfile

How to set the make file or my project so that during the build process it automatically creates a log file from the output of compiler errors and messages for c or c++ projects.

Comment: you can do `make | tee log` That will output to standard output and save to a log file.

Comment: Each compiler and linker has options to produce a listing that includes its diagnostic messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just i/o redirection and you can do it in many different ways.

1. `Append` each error after compiling that file in makefile.
   `@gcc -c file1.c 2>> error.log`
2. As Martin york has said, `make | tee log`

These are just some ways I can think of now. Do go through [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-i-o-redirection) for learning on I/O redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "make" and combine it with "gcc" or any other compiler of your choice.

Then check these other posts on the same topic, if I understand your question correctly, but if you just want the make output use "make" and "tee". `make | tee log`. This will create a log file for you with all the generated text from the make process.

[How do I make a Makefile to log both command and its output to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54933242/how-do-i-make-a-makefile-to-log-both-command-and-its-output-to-a-file)

[How do I capture all of my compiler's output to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297536/how-do-i-capture-all-of-my-compilers-output-to-a-file/2297552)